# mt4j and Processing library : clean image resources

Tags: java, processing, mt4j

I'm using mt4j library in a quite big project, in which scenes are pushed and poped regularly ; mt4j uses Processing library to deal with images.

We use the `loadImage()` method to load images, but I don't know how to delete these images from memory when a scene is poped ; we have actually memory problems, because the memory used increases during the application running time..

Do you have some idea ?

Thanks
Jérémy

EDIT :

I just wrote an ImageManager class :

```
package managers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mt4j.MTApplication;

import processing.core.PImage;




public class ImageManager {

private static ImageManager mImageManager = null;

protected MTApplication mApp;
protected Map< String, PImage > mImages;

protected PImage mTempImg;

private ImageManager( MTApplication app ) {
    mApp = app;
    mImages = new HashMap< String, PImage >();
}

public static synchronized ImageManager getInstance( MTApplication app ) {
    if( mImageManager == null ) {
        mImageManager = new ImageManager( app );
    }

    return mImageManager;
}

/**
 * Load or retrieve img in memory
 * 
 * @param path Path to the image
 * @return <PImage> the image
 */
public PImage getImage( String path ) {
    // Search for image
    if( mImages.containsKey( path ) ) {
        System.out.println( "ImageManager::getImage : image found !" );
        mTempImg = mImages.get( path );
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println( "ImageManager::getImage : image not found, loading" );
        mTempImg = mApp.loadImage( path );
        mImages.put( path, mTempImg );
    }

    return mTempImg;
}
}
```

Here is my problem : I thought that it would help me with memory problems, but I still see memory increase every time I load an image. An exemple of use :

```
ImageManager imgManager = ImageManager.getInstance( (MTApplication) app );
            PImage image = imgManager.getImage( getPathToIcons() + imagesNames[i] );
            //PImage image = app.loadImage(getPathToIcons() + imagesNames[i]);
            mSceneImages.add( image );
```

Any idea ? Thanks

EDIT 2 : In fact, this method is working great :) Problem solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : finally I've tryed to delete images at a time, but it doesn't clean memory... It's like there still is some other references that I can't find... Any idea to be sure of memory cleaning ?

My solution to the problem : ImageManager class

```
package managers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mt4j.MTApplication;

import processing.core.PImage;




public class ImageManager {

private static ImageManager mImageManager = null;

protected MTApplication mApp;
protected Map< String, PImage > mImages;

protected PImage mTempImg;

private ImageManager( MTApplication app ) {
    mApp = app;
    mImages = new HashMap< String, PImage >();
}

public static synchronized ImageManager getInstance( MTApplication app ) {
    if( mImageManager == null ) {
        mImageManager = new ImageManager( app );
    }

    return mImageManager;
}

/**
 * Load or retrieve img in memory
 * 
 * @param path Path to the image
 * @return <PImage> the image
 */
public PImage getImage( String path ) {
    // Search for image
    if( mImages.containsKey( path ) ) {
        System.out.println( "ImageManager::getImage : image found !" );
        mTempImg = mImages.get( path );
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println( "ImageManager::getImage : image not found, loading" );
        mTempImg = mApp.loadImage( path );
        mImages.put( path, mTempImg );
    }

    return mTempImg;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe just reuse them? First, image1 = loadImage(oneImage), later image1 = loadImage(anotherImage)?

Comment: That would be a good idea, but actually most of my variables are locally, so it won't be possible. That's also another point, I don't understand why these vars are not really unreferenced after the function's scope

Comment: Well if they are local they should be automatically disposed after they are out of scope, shoudn't they?

Answer (score 2):

For memory leaks in java you might look into packratting. I haven't found a great solution for processing other than running

> top -s 5

(on unix systems) and watching the memory usage until it hangs. I recently worked on a datavis project where I was creating potentially thousands of blitts (in my case images of text to use in opengl) in an ArrayList. Originally I was recreating these arrays on the fly everytime I would load data and it was contributing to a "memory leak".

In my case I tried nulling out the object references and calling the garbage collector specifically. I think it may have to do with the fact that processing is calling your void draw() method potentially 60+ times per second, but it seems that it never seemed to let go of the references.

What I did to correct the issue was to load all the images / create the blits only once in the setup method() and only to append new items to the ArrayList when there was new data.

Prior to this I would just recreate the entire ArrayList on the fly, because it seemed fast enough, but when running for a long time had this horrible memory leak issue.

Now I was just assigned the blit to this reference, rather than creating a new object and ArrayList each time. It was much more efficient and didn't suffer from the same memory issue.

For example something like this (run thousands of times in a loop):

```
tempImage = imageArrayList.get(i); // just assigns a reference, does not create a new object
```

instead of something like this:

```
tempImage = loadImage("image.jpg"); // this creates a new object every time it is called
```

Comment: I was thinking of creating an image manager, and assign an ID to every images I could need, so I would be sure that theses images are not loaded multiple times. I think it's quite close to your solution, isn't it ?

Comment: I just wrote an edit with my class, can you have a look at it please ?

Comment: Looks like you resolved your issue. The code above looks good to me. The problem I ran into had to do with instantiating objects into ArrayLists and losing the reference to the previous object(s).

Answer (score 1):

LoadImage returns a PImage object. If you discard these PImage references, then System.gc(), the garbage collector, should remove them. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yep, in fact most of the vars are used locally, and are normally out of scope after the method, but it doesn't seem to work great.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Processing 2.x? If so, maybe [this](http://forum.processing.org/topic/pimage-memory-leak-example) thread in Processing forum can be the answer. Apparently there is a memory leak using images in 2.x. And also they point an work around that you might want to try, here the example with the hack from PhiLho in the thread I pointed.
HTH.

```
void draw()
{
  PImage img = createImage(width, height, RGB);
  image(img, 0, 0);
  g.removeCache(img);// this is avoiding the leak
  println(frameCount + " " + g.getCache(img));
}
```